# Add each product items separately to a shopping cart

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, quote

I want to make adding to the shopping cart as a separate item on every action of clicking to a button **Add to Cart**. If the customer clicks **Add to Cart** a couple of times he/she should see different items in the shopping cart with **qty 1**.

I know about [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222763/how-to-add-each-product-items-separatly-to-a-shopping-cart) but this is not having an answer.

So is it possible to somehow achieve this?

Comment: Yes this is achievable.. Do you want this for simple product ?

Comment: @aravind I want this for all product types.

Comment: I have done this task only for simple products and configurable..

Comment: @aravind, please share your knowledge about simple and configurable, I'll try to adapt it for other products. Thank.

Comment: have you created plugin with afterRepresentProduct ? as mentioned in link provided?

Answer (score 2):

Create di.xml in your custom module,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd" >
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
        <plugin name="beforeDispatch" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\ItemPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create After Method for representProduct,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote;

class ItemPlugin
{
    public function afterRepresentProduct(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject, $result)
    {
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is the same as in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222763/how-to-add-each-product-items-separatly-to-a-shopping-cart. It only works if customer add product with qty 1, but not if with qty > 1

Comment: Ok i will post another answer..

Comment: Waiting for solution on this

Answer (score 0):

Overide `form.phtml` in `vendor/magento/module_catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml`, and change form action to custom controller.

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml`

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $formSubmitUrl = $this->getUrl('routeId/path/controller');
?>

<div class="product-add-form">
    <form data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
          action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $formSubmitUrl ?>" method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_top') ?>
        <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content') ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
                <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
            <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom') ?>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'priceBox'
    ], function($){
        var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
            dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getId()) ?>]',
            priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
    });
</script>
```

Then create `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml` for controller in custom module,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="yourfrontname" id="yourfrontname">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Then in controller add the logic,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class YourController extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart
{

    /**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 */
public function __construct(
    ProductRepository $productRepository,
    FormKey $formKey,
    ProductFactory $product,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
    CustomerCart $cart
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $scopeConfig,
        $checkoutSession,
        $storeManager,
        $formKeyValidator,
        $cart
    );
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->product = $product;
}


  /**
 * Initialize product instance from request data
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|false
 */
protected function _initProduct()
{
    $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    if ($productId) {
        $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class
        )->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Add product to shopping cart action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $postValues = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $productId = $postValues['product'];
    $formKey = $postValues['form_key'];
    $qty = $postValues['qty'];

    for($qtyVal = 1 ; $qtyVal <= $qty; $qtyVal++) {
        try {
            $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId,
                'qty' => 1
            );
             $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
              $product = $this->_initProduct();
             /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message = __(
                        'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                        $product->getName()
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                }
                return $this->goBack(null, $product);
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }
    }
    $this->cart->save();
}


/**
 * Resolve response
 *
 * @param string $backUrl
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @return $this|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 */
protected function goBack($backUrl = null, $product = null)
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
        return parent::_goBack($backUrl);
    }

    $result = [];

    if ($backUrl || $backUrl = $this->getBackUrl()) {
        $result['backUrl'] = $backUrl;
    } else {
        if ($product && !$product->getIsSalable()) {
            $result['product'] = [
                'statusText' => __('Out of stock')
            ];
        }
    }

    $this->getResponse()->representJson(
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($result)
    );
}
}
```

Comment: do you try this, it works? I see that in ```$this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);``` 
first argument don't defined

Comment: I have updated the answer.. I did few customization, so i edited according to the need..

Comment: What happened does this works?

Comment: doesn't work...